# Missing language toolbar in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, language, toolbar, regional-settings

My language toolbar for Korean used to show up in Windows 7 but one day it disappeared.

When I checked the superbar property, the language bar entry has disappeared as shown:

[image]

I checked my regional settings to see if the keyboard is still there or not; it is still there.

[image]

Can anyone point out to me what I am doing wrong? How can I get the language toolbar back?

Comment: Which version of Windows-7 are you using? Professional, Ultimate?

Comment: Windows 7 Enterprise 32bit

Comment: A lot of people would love to obliterate the language bar from their computer. Maybe you just need to trade computers with someone on whose computer it keeps coming back. :)

Comment: @Scott: I hope my disappearing toolbar is not a feature of "Enterprise" edition ;)

Comment: And what happen if you go to Text Services and Input Languages->Language Bar than choose Docked in the Taskbar and press Apply button?

Comment: What Maria has written is important. You are checking one tab in settings, but not the more relevant one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Language bar mysteriously came back after a few restarts (didn't show up for like for the first 2 restarts for some reason).

Comment: This is not really an answer, you never mentioned how it was solved.